# Java making a drawCircle method calling drawOval

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics

I need to make a drawCircle method that looks like

```
public void drawCircle(int x, int y, int radius)
```

that draws a circle with that center and radius.  The drawCircle method needs to call drawOval.  I am not sure how I can call drawOval from my drawCircle method without passing Graphics to it.  Is this possible?

Heres what I have:

```
import java.awt.*;   
import javax.swing.*;

class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(new MyPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
class MyPanel extends JPanel
{

    MyPanel()
    {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,250));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
    {
        super.paintComponent(page);
        drawCircle(50,50,20);
    }

    private void drawCircle(int x, int y, int radius)
    {
        drawOval(x - radius, y - radius, radius*2, radius*2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have to do it with passing a Graphics?

Comment: don't you have to call drawOval in paintComponent like g.drawOval(), where g is Graphics?

Comment: By 'passing Graphics to it' are you referring to a Java library object?  Post more complete code.

Comment: What object are you trying to call drawCircle on?
If you plan to make a call to drawOval from the java.awt.* library then you will need a Graphics object to call the method on yes. Please give more context though.

Comment: yes the Graphics I am referring to is the Java library object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the graphics context by calling `getGraphics()` on a swing component. But i would still create my drawing methods to accept the graphics context.

For instance

```
private void drawCircle(Graphics g, int x, int y, int radius) {
   g.fillOval(x-radius, y-radius, radius*2, radius*2)
}
```

Alternatively,

```
private void drawCircle(int x, int y, int radius) {
  getGraphics().fillOval(x-radius, y-radius, radius*2, radius*2)
}
```

Be aware of the fact that `getGraphics()` can return `null` however. You are much better off calling your drawCircle() method from within the paint() method and passing it the Graphics context.

E.g.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
  super.paint(g);
  drawCircle(g, 10, 10, 5, 5);
}
```

Comment: True, but this is a homework question. If this can't be done without Graphics, then I'll just tell my professor.

Comment: Ya, im guessing its returning null when I'm testing it on Windows, however, it works on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

public static Shape getCircle(
                        final double x,
                        final double y,
                        final double r
                             ) {

    return new Ellipse2D.Double(x - r, y - r, r * 2, r * 2);
}
```

Advantages:

- You don't have to pass or get the Graphics context.
- You can choose whether to draw or fill the circle without changing the Method (e.g. do `g.draw(getCircle(x, y, r));` or `g.fill...` in your paint() Method).
- You use AWT draw Method syntax to actually draw/fill the circle.
- You get a circle in double precision coordinates.

You said that "The drawCircle method needs to call drawOval.", but maybe you were just not aware of the alternative.